# New Chrome Web Store supporting Google Analytics 4: How do I find out the admin?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

Chrome Web Store now supports Google Analytics 4 - there's an announcement for this on Mar 28, 2023 which you can google.

I am unable to find out how to identify who the "admin" account is. The link within Chrome Web Store takes you to a Google Analytics 4 project (which is created by Google). If you click on "Account Access Management" under 'Admin' button (bottom left of screen), there's a "Request access" button to ask for access but I have no idea where this request is going.

Does the request go to void?

I've searched and asked other developers. This is a very new feature with no official documentation. I'm looking for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can't be an admin and instead need to modify permissions by using [group publisher](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/google-analytics/#grant-access)